# Limit attempts for inputting in form

Tags: php, html, mysql

how do I set a number of attempts for a user to enter the one time password? 
If user enter the wrong password for the 3rd time, he will be auto logged out and will need to login again. 
Do I need to create a new column of "number of attempts" on SQL table?

```
            <form method="POST" action="" onSubmit="return validate(this)" >
                <input type="button" value="Click for OTP" onclick="openotp()" />  <br/>  <br/> 

                    <table id="table">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="alt"><label for="otp">Enter the 6-digit iBanking OTP </label></td>
                            <td><input type="password" name="otp" maxlength="6"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Click to submit OTP">
            </form>
                <?php
                $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
             if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                 $otp = $_POST['otp'];

                 $query = "SELECT otp FROM user where user_id='$user_id'";
                 $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
                 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                 $rand = $row['otp'];

    if ($otp == $rand) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id='$user_id' AND otp='$otp'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    echo "<script>location.href='index.php'</script>";


    } else  {
echo "Wrong password";
    }

             }

             ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a session variable

```
 $_SESSION['attempts']
```

and then in the conditional statement where it fails increment the $_SESSION['attempts'] by 1.  then on your page say

```
  if ($_SESSION['attempts'] < 3)
  {
     //do stuff
  }
  else
  {
      echo "too many login failures";
  }
```

Comment: should I create an array for the  $_SESSION['attempts']?

Comment: How do I increase the session by 1 when it fails?

Comment: In the else part of your login script (where login fails) add $_SESSION['attempts']++;

Comment: How do I set back the attempts to 0 on else { }?

Comment: if you set it back to 0 then the user would be able to continue trying to login.  anyways, to do this you would $_SESSION['attempts'] = 0;